# Nested Resource Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
resources :patients do
 collection do
   get 'new_import'
   post 'import'
 end
```

How can I have the following urls?

```
/patients/import (GET) -->ACTION: new_import

/patients/import (POST) --> ACTION: import
```

Right NOW THE URLS ARE:

```
/patients/new_import (GET) -->ACTION: new_import

/patients/import (POST) --> ACTION: import
```

I must be able to do this WITHOUT doing:

```
 match 'patients/import' => 'patients#new_import', :via => :get
 match 'patients/import' => 'patients#import', :via => :post
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources :patients do
  collection do
    get  'import' => :new_import
    post 'import' => :import
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I will award your bounty in 22 hours. I am wondering why this isn't documented!

Answer (score 1):

Like you've written on top:

```
resources :patients do
 collection do
   get 'new_import'
   post 'import'
 end
end
```

Do you have any errors while trying to access this urls?

Comment: I don't think I made the question clear enough. I want to use the same url of patients/import for both actions. One via a get and one via a post. I will update the question to be more clear.